# How to return multiple components in render function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made 3 components `Batcomponent`, `Bowlcomponent`, `Fieldcomponent`. I am passing `props` to each of these components. When the string matches to `bat` or `field` or `bowl` that particular component is rendered and shown on web page. I am returning `{renderData}` inside `return()`.

Code:

```
render(){

if(this.props.type === "bat"){
 renderData = (<Batcomponent 
    prop1 = this.props.type.name
    prop2 = this.props.matches
    prop3 = this.props.email
    />)
}else if(this.props.type === "bowl"){
  renderData = (<Bowlcomponent 
    prop1 = this.props.type.name
    prop2 = this.props.matches
    prop3 = this.props.email
    />)
}else if(this.props.type === "field"){
    renderData = (<Fieldcomponent 
    prop1 = this.props.type.name
    prop2 = this.props.matches
    prop3 = this.props.email
    />)
}

}

return(){
    <div>
       {renderData}
    </div>
}
```

Now I want to add Piechart component inside `renderData`.
What I tried:

```
render(){

if(this.props.type === "bat"){
 renderData = (<Batcomponent 
    prop1 = this.props.type.name
    prop2 = this.props.matches
    prop3 = this.props.email
    />
    <Pie prop1 = this.props.type.name />
    )
}else if(this.props.type === "bowl"){
  renderData = (<Bowlcomponent 
    prop1 = this.props.type.name
    prop2 = this.props.matches
    prop3 = this.props.email
    />
    <Pie prop1 = this.props.type.name/>
    )
}else if(this.props.type === "field"){
    renderData = (<Fieldcomponent 
    prop1 = this.props.type.name
    prop2 = this.props.matches
    prop3 = this.props.email
    />
    <Pie prop1 = this.props.type.name/>
    )
}

}

return(){
    <div>
       {renderData}
    </div>
}
```

Above code does not work how can I add additional components inside `renderData` ?

If I do `renderData = (<FirstComponent />)` it works but if I do like this -> `renderData = (<FirstComponent /> <SecondComponent/>)` it does not work why ?

Comment: wrapped RenderData in a div or a Fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...

```
renderData = (
  <div>
     <Fieldcomponent 
     prop1 = this.props.type.name
     prop2 = this.props.matches
     prop3 = this.props.email
     />
     <Pie prop1 = this.props.type.name/>
  </div>
)
```

JSX expects components to be wrapped in a div / fragment, even internal components that you have defined in a variable/function call.

Depending on your react version, you could use `Fragment` or `<>`.

This can alternatively be done with *Fragments*

```
renderData = (
  <Fragment>
     <Fieldcomponent 
     prop1 = this.props.type.name
     prop2 = this.props.matches
     prop3 = this.props.email
     />
     <Pie prop1 = this.props.type.name/>
  </Fragment>
)
```

However, I'd probably recommend cleaning the code further...

```
render(){
  return(
    <div>
    { 
      this.props.type === 'bat' ? <Bat {...props} /> :
      this.props.type === 'bowl' ? <Bowl {...props} /> :
      this.props.type === 'field' ? <Field {...props} /> : <Default {...props} />
    }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You said wrap it inside `div` but in `return()` I have wrapped it inside a `div`

Comment: My question is different in my case why should I add multiple components inside `div` because I am adding `renderData` inside `<div>` in `return()`

Comment: I've simplified the code because components Bat could have any number of components; and it's even better if you used a reusuable component defined elsewhere.

By defining any JSX component, you are required to enclose that in a `div` tag, regardless of whether you set it in `render()`, `renderData` or otherwise. - This is why Fragments were created, as React still renders a div for you.

Answer (score 2):

This code does not work because adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag.

React 16 introduced Fragments, which let you wrap JSX expressions without adding an extra div.

**If you're using React 16, use Fragments:**

```
 if (this.props.type === "bat") {
      renderData = (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Batcomponent
          prop1={this.props.type.name}
          prop2={this.props.matches}
          prop3={this.props.email}
        />
        <Pie prop1={this.props.type.name}/>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
   }else if ...
```

**If you aren't using React 16, wrap them in a div instead:**

```
 if (this.props.type === "bat") {
      renderData = (
        <div>
          <Batcomponent
          prop1={this.props.type.name}
          prop2={this.props.matches}
          prop3={this.props.email}
        />
        <Pie prop1={this.props.type.name}/>
        </div>
    )
   }else if ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way you can handle this is by making a kind of hash table (Just an object containing multiple components) in that way will scale as much as you want, so it could be something like

```
const components = {
  bat: BatComponent,
  bowl: BowlComponent,
  field: FieldComponent
}
```

Now make a function that will choose the right component to show

```
renderComponent(){
  const { type, ...restProps } = this.props;
  const Component = components[type]
  return <Component {...restProps } />
}
```

Now in your render function

```
render(){
  return {this.renderComponent()}
}
```

If you need to return 2 components maybe it would be better to wrap those 2 components into one and add it to the object that contains the components (hash table)

Answer (score 1):

here is a clean exp using the **children** prop:

```
const CompA = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Im component A</h3>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

see the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kvk01lmqr) exp.